# Running old .exe programs under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

My new computer used Windows 7. I have some old compiled BASIC programs and other .exe progrms that will not run under Windows.  What shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

Is it Windows 7 Professional?  You could use virtual pc.

Answer (score 1):

If they are old DOS programs your best bet would by running them in [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/), an MS-DOS emulator.

Other than that you could use a virtual machine.  Windows 7 Professional or Ultimate can download XP Mode which is a Windows XP virtual machine.  Otherwise there is VMWare or Virtual Box, but both of those would require a separate copy of Windows loaded on them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a 64-bit version of Windows then you will need a system emulator to run DOS applications since [Long Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_mode) does not support running [Virtual 8086 Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_8086_mode) processes.